# Need to get latitude and longitude from google map API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox

I'm using the map which I got from above link. It works fine in my website. When I search for a place ,that location  will be shown in map. I need to get its longitude and latitude and should be displayed in a textbox when I click on a place on Google map.

The code is shown below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
.controls {
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 32px;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

#pac-input {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-left: 12px;
  padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 300px;
}

#pac-input:focus {
  border-color: #4d90fe;
}

.pac-container {
  font-family: Roboto;
}

#type-selector {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4d90fe;
  padding: 5px 11px 0px 11px;
}

#type-selector label {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

    </style>
    <title>Places Searchbox</title>
    <style>
      #target {
        width: 345px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
// This example adds a search box to a map, using the Google Place Autocomplete
// feature. People can enter geographical searches. The search box will return a
// pick list containing a mix of places and predicted search terms.

function initAutocomplete() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2195},
    zoom: 13,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
  var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
  var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

  // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
  map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
    searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
  });

  var markers = [];
  // [START region_getplaces]
  // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
  // more details for that place.
  searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

    if (places.length == 0) {
      return;
    }

    // Clear out the old markers.
    markers.forEach(function(marker) {
      marker.setMap(null);
    });
    markers = [];

    // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    places.forEach(function(place) {
      var icon = {
        url: place.icon,
        size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
      };

      // Create a marker for each place.
      markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        icon: icon,
        title: place.name,
        position: place.geometry.location
      }));

      if (place.geometry.viewport) {
        // Only geocodes have viewport.
        bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
      } else {
        bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
      }
    });
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  });
  // [END region_getplaces]
}


    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAkwr5rmzY9btU08sQlU9N0qfmo8YmE91Y&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
         async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
places.forEach(function(place) {
console.log("lat: "+place.geometry.location.lat()+" lng: "+place.geometry.location.lng())
//etc
```

Comment: Do I need to replace the code places.forEach(function(place) {
      var icon = {
        url: place.icon,
        size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)  with the above code???

Comment: no, the above code will log the coordinates you are looking for to the console. You should add that line and leave everything else. Although if you want that data in text boxes you will need to add the textboxes to the html, then populate them like: `document.getElementById('latbox').value=place.geometry.location.lat();`

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.

Comment: @lucas ... Actually I need to get each coodinates when I click on a position on map. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

you would need to put an event listener on the map object, then get the coordinates of the click event when it happens:

```
map.addListener('click', function (locationdata) {
  document.getElementById("latitude").value =locationdata.latLng.lat();
  document.getElementById("longitude").value =locationdata.latLng.lng();
});
```

and adjust your html accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You already have the location data at place collection, you can use loop .  here is the simplest way to do this .

```
 for (var i = 0, place; place = places[i]; i++) {

      alert("latitude: "+place.geometry.location.lat()+" longitude: "+place.geometry.location.lng());


 });
```

if you want to add this in a array

```
var locationArray[];

for (var i = 0, place; place = places[i]; i++) {

      alert("latitude: "+place.geometry.location.lat()+" longitude: "+place.geometry.location.lng());

      locationArray[i]= places[i].geometry.location;

 });
```

here is the code example [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nurfarazi/1ospjbto/)

Comment: Hi...im getting coordinates. Actually I need to get each coodinates when I click on a position on map. How can I do it?

Comment: check the edited answer , if it helps you don't forget to mark it correct

Answer (score 0):

Add a listener to each marker, use it to add that marker's position to the text box.

```
  // Create a marker for each place.
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    icon: icon,
    title: place.name,
    position: place.geometry.location
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click',function(evt) {
      document.getElementById('coordinates').value = marker.getPosition().toUrlValue(6);
  });
  markers.push(marker);
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/3ewj9jhr/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
// This example adds a search box to a map, using the Google Place Autocomplete
// feature. People can enter geographical searches. The search box will return a
// pick list containing a mix of places and predicted search terms.
// clicked marker coordinates will be placed in the input text element with id="coordinates"

function initAutocomplete() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: -33.8688,
      lng: 151.2195
    },
    zoom: 13,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
  var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
  var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

  // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
  map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
    searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
  });

  var markers = [];
  // [START region_getplaces]
  // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
  // more details for that place.
  searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

    if (places.length == 0) {
      return;
    }

    // Clear out the old markers.
    markers.forEach(function(marker) {
      marker.setMap(null);
    });
    markers = [];

    // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    places.forEach(function(place) {
      var icon = {
        url: place.icon,
        size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
      };

      // Create a marker for each place.
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        icon: icon,
        title: place.name,
        position: place.geometry.location
      });
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(evt) {
        document.getElementById('coordinates').value = marker.getPosition().toUrlValue(6);
      });
      markers.push(marker);
      if (place.geometry.viewport) {
        // Only geocodes have viewport.
        bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
      } else {
        bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
      }
    });
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  });
  // [END region_getplaces]
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initAutocomplete);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
.controls {
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 32px;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
#pac-input {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-left: 12px;
  padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 300px;
}
#pac-input:focus {
  border-color: #4d90fe;
}
.pac-container {
  font-family: Roboto;
}
#type-selector {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4d90fe;
  padding: 5px 11px 0px 11px;
}
#type-selector label {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 300;
}
#target {
  width: 345px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<input id="coordinates" type="text" size="30" />
<input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: @geocodezip...But how to change coordinates when I click on easch places??

Comment: The coordinates change when you click on a marker.  There can be multiple results from selecting one entry in the search box.